# C# linkbutton not firing in Gridview within Updatepanel

Tags: redirect, gridview, updatepanel, linkbutton

I'm hoping someone can help me. I have searched the web for a suitable answer but haven't found one.

I have the following `LinkButton` in a `GridView` (`GridView2`) which is within an `UpdatePanel` set to `UpdateMode='Conditional'`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblSCcomments" runat="server" Width="80" 
        Text='<%#Eval("ShortCode")%>' CommandName="hyperSC" 
        OnCommand="GridView2_Command" 
        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ShortCode")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

with this code behind:

```
protected void GridView2_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "hyperSC")
    {
        string sc = e.CommandArgument.ToString();            
        lblShortCode.Text = sc;
        Session["scode"] = sc;
        Server.Transfer("~/MemberPages/reviews.aspx");
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately, when I click on the link the command is not firing. But this was working outside of the `UpdatePanel`. I don't need the `Gridview` to refresh, just need to populate the `Session` variable and `lblShortCode` Label with the selected row `Shortcode` and be redirected to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `OnRowCommand` event in your GridView like `<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">` and do you *.CS* code in this event:

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "hyperSC")
    {
        string sc = e.CommandArgument.ToString();            
        lblShortCode.Text = sc;
        Session["scode"] = sc;
        Server.Transfer("~/MemberPages/reviews.aspx");
    }
}
```

And remove the `OnCommand` event from LinkButton.